# How to get the URL of an HTML href Attribute containing an .ics file with Python?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get the URL of an `.ics` file off of a webpage containing an `.ics` calendar. For example, https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar, but it should work for any webpage containing `.ics`.
Below is my naive attempt (which doesn't print anything and I can't figure out why):

```
import urllib2
import requests
import bs4

def get_ics_url(url):

    #page = requests.get('https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar').content

    page = requests.get(url).content
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    links = soup.find_all('a')

    for link in links:
        if link.get('href')[-4:]=='.ics':
            endout = type(link.get('href'))

            print endout
        break
```

What am I doing wrong, and what is a better way to obtain the URL of an `.ics` file that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `break` in your code will stop the script after just one iteration, you need to indent it once more, to place it into the `if` (or use `return` instead). Currently it will break the `for` no matter what the result of the `if` is.

There's a second issue which is that there are `<a>` elements without `href` attribute, this will cause the script to fail before it reaches any .ics links:

```
if link.get('href')[-4:]=='.ics':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

For example:

```
<a name="main-content"></a>
<a class="cal-export" title="Note: Past events are not included">Export</a>
```

You can fix this by checking links for `link.get('href') != None` before doing array operations on it.

Fixed code:

```
import urllib2
import requests
import bs4

def get_ics_url(url):
    page = requests.get(url).content
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    links = soup.find_all('a')

    for link in links:
        if link.get('href') != None and link.get('href')[-4:]=='.ics':
            endout = link.get('href')
            return endout

print get_ics_url('https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar')
```

Comment: Thank you for a great, concise answer.